Why SwiftUI Picker does not change value?
I have this simple code:
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {

    @State private var selectedTab: String = "tab1"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Mode", selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("tab1").tag("tab1")
                Text("tab2").tag("tab2")
                Text("tab3").tag("tab3")
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .padding([.horizontal, .top])
        
            Form {
                switch selectedTab {
                    case "tab1":
                        TabOneView()
                    case "tab2":
                        TabTwoView()
                    case "tab3":
                        TabThreeView()
                    default:
                        TabOneView()
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Title")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

When I try this in the preview it works correctly, but when I use it in the app, where this View is called with a NavigationLink from another View the picker seems freeze: pressing another option does not change the value and so also the view does not change (also visually, the default option remains selected).
The parent View:
struct ParentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            // some other code
        
            Section(header: Text("SUBVIEWS")) {
                NavigationLink {
                    ExampleView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Example")
                }
                NavigationLink {
                    Example2View()
                } label: {
                    Text("Example2")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("ParentView")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

I also tried to print the values with in method .onChange on the variable selectedTab, but it does not print anything (synonym that the value is not changed).
This is how it looks like:


Please show the real code then - the code "where this View is called with a NavigationLink from another View".

I still can't reproduce the issue after implementing the last edit.

Using .zIndex(1) on the Picker solves the problem.
